# Cannot deserialize the JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type ' ' because type requires JSON object (e.g. {“name”:“value”})

Tags: c#, json, xamarin

I have JSON returning in the following format:

```
{
"Items": [
    {
        "unique_id": "11111111111",
        "rages": {
            "rage_content": "Hello rage 2",
            "date_stamp": "21/07/2017",
            "id": 2
        }
    },
    {
        "unique_id": "2222222222",
        "rages": {
            "rage_content": "Hello rage 1",
            "date_stamp": "21/07/2017",
            "id": 1
        }
    }
],
"Count": 2,
"ScannedCount": 2
}
```

And I have the following 2 classes defined:

`Items.cs`:

```
namespace ragevent_A0._0._1
{
    class Items
    {
        public String rage_id { get; set; }
        public rage rage { get; set; }

    }
}
```

`rage.cs`:

```
class rage
{
    public String rage_content { get; set; }
    public String date_stamp { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
}
```

I am using the following code in order to attempt to deseralize the JSON returned above:

```
List<Items> data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Items>>(json);
```

However, I am not able to successfully deserialize the data due to the above error. I have tried a few solutions online, however I have not managed to find a solution which works with the format of my returned JSON. I have used a JSON formatter and it is formatted correctly, so that shouldn't be the issue.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Try http://json2csharp.com to build the class structure

Comment: your c# class has `rage_id ` while your JSON object has `"unique_id"`. Is that no problem? Also you are not deserializing an array of objects but and object containing that array

Comment: @danielspaniol No, that will not raise any exception

Comment: Another nice VS extension is https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DangKhuong.JSONtoC

Comment: @Sir Rufo json2csharp sorted me out, thank you!

Comment: @Paulj at the moment I prefer https://jsonutils.com/

Answer (score 2):

For the posted JSON data below should be the model you need (credit: http://json2csharp.com/). There is mismatch between the property name `rage_id`. You can use `JsonProperty` attribute

```
public class Rages
{
    public string rage_content { get; set; }
    public string date_stamp { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    [JsonProperty(Name="rage_id")]
    public string unique_id { get; set; }
    public Rages rages { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public int ScannedCount { get; set; }
}
```

Your deserialization should be

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

Comment: Ah ok awesome, cheers. I have added this into my application however I am still getting an error when trying to deseralize. Sorry about the unique_id - it was a typo. I am using this to deseralize: List<RootObject> data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(json);

Comment: @CallumHolden The json document describes a **single** object and not an array. An array would start with [ and an object start with { - do you see?

Comment: @CallumHolden, you don't have an array of root object. see edit in answer.

Comment: Ah ok I see, so essentially in this case is the 'Items' a single object? My main goal here is to have each one of those objects under 'Items' passed into a list so that I can bind it to a listview on screen.

Comment: @CallumHolden No, the json is a single object with an Items property which is a collection (many items)

Comment: @CallumHolden, you should deserialize it to `RootObject` and then while binding to listview can say `lstview.DataSource = data.Items`

Comment: @SirRufo Ah I see! That makes more sense now. So I have a single object with the property 'Items' and 'Items' is a collection of many 'Items'. Got it! Thanks for the json2csharp link also, that is really useful!

Comment: Ah the edit worked! I see how this is working now, so instead of putting it straight into a list - I first have to put it into a var and then iterate over the var to pull out the data into a list. Makes sense, thanks!

Comment: @CallumHolden I have the strange feeling you did not get the whole point. Anyway, you should have a working solution for this ;o)

Comment: @SirRufo, was about to write the same ... so +1 :)

Comment: @CallumHolden, you don't need to loop through `data` after deserializing .. you can directly use the `Items` property for binding purpose to your cntrol

Comment: Ah wait yes I understand more now, yes I can just bind that to my list for my control without having to loop over it. Awesome! Thanks for the help guys! :)

Comment: @CallumHolden, consider accepting the answer if it helped by clicking the check button